# QGIS 3.4.3 Color region bounded by certain lines

Tags: qgis, color

How do I color in the certain regions that are bounded by lines?

I'm completely new to QGIS.

[image: as seen here there's different lines from different layers, but I want the regions created by the lines to be different colors]

Comment: Use the layer symbology properties - https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#symbology-properties

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you need to `right click` your layer in `Layers list`, select `Properties` and then `Symbology`. Here you can change the styling.

[image] [image]

[image]

Check out this short Lesson: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html Its pretty much the same in 3.4.3